# Microsoft Lists UI in SharePoint List UI instead of modern SPO UI

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, site, microsoft-lists

From a few days, some list from sites have interface like Microsoft Lists instead of the modern SharePoint view interface.

The view/ui/ux/interface isn't a big deal, but I lost all navigation in my sites is gone and without menu work is very annoying.

I heard from other people is not only in my case. So it's a bug from Microsoft or some quite unannounced change? How back to modern view?

[image]

Comment: I don't have this issue on our SharePoint tenant. How are you accessing the lists in SharePoint. Can you add the steps you followed to go to SharePoint lists or URL you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this issue on our SharePoint tenant. When I open the SharePoint list from SharePoint site, it opens with the SharePoint view (with site navigation, etc).

If you are opening the list saved in SharePoint site from "Microsoft Lists" app/site (Eg. `https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/personal/gsanap_contoso_com/_layouts/15/Lists.aspx`), then it is default behavior to open the list with "Microsoft Lists" UI and not SharePoint UI with site navigation, etc.

Follow below steps to open the SharePoint list in SharePoint view:

1. Go to your SharePoint site.
2. Click on Settings (gear) icon from top right corner and select **Site contents**.
3. Locate your SharePoint list and click on list name. It should open the list in SharePoint view

Also, make sure you are not using this query string parameter while opening the SharePoint list: `env=WebViewList`

For example:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/Lists/MyList/AllItems.aspx?env=WebViewList
```

If you use this query string parameter with the SharePoint list URL, it open the list with "Microsoft Lists" UI.

---

**Update (9 Sep 2023)**:

Looks like this is a new feature released by Microsoft for SharePoint lists and your admin can change the settings to always show the site navigation using PowerShell:

[image]

---

**Update (11 Nov 2023)**:

Looks like Microsoft is rolling back this feature and SharePoint UI or site navigation will be visible as is and will not be affected by this feature release:

[image]

- Link to feature related [blog post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/microsoft-lists-easier-better-faster-stronger/bc-p/3842882)
- Link to [Microsoft 365 Roadmap ID](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=124867)

Comment: Nope, with that env still I have 'Lists' experience. I try open lists form site contents - no deferents.

On a daily basis, I don't use "Microsoft Lists" so for 100% isn't some mistake. On Monday, I had an old traditional/modern view, to day one of my site have in all list that view, some sites with some lists changed. So it is not like my problem with just one site. I spoke with college, and he has the same issue, different tenant.

Comment: You have to **avoid** using the `env=WebViewList` so that it will not open in Microsoft Lists view.

Comment: Are you using targeted release or standard release tenant? Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: I have tried it in 3 different tenants and it is working fine for me. I will suggest you to raise a support ticket with Microsoft directly and report this behavior: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support

Comment: Yes, I'm a targeted release user. But I tested it with two other colleagues.  One have new experience, one no. But for now, all people who aren't in a targeted release users how old experience.

Comment: In that case, it might the temporary issue at Microsoft end. Try raising support ticket with Microsoft directly.

Comment: Updated the answer with more information.

Comment: All is OK, I think it was some bug. All list back to as usually looks a few days after my post, without my further actions.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft is rolling back this feature release for SharePoint list. Check updated answer for more information.

Comment: I am glad it is working for you now. Can you Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily? It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list and closes the item.